# ValueError when downloading a file from an S3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am sucessfully downloading an image file to my local computer from my S3 bucket using the following:

```
import os
import boto3
import botocore

files = ['images/dog_picture.png']
bucket = 'animals'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for file in files:
   s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(file, os.path.basename(file))
```

However, when I try to specify the directory to which the image should be saved on my local machine [as is done in the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file):

```
   s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(file, os.path.basename(file), '/home/user/storage/new_image.png')
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Invalid extra_args key '/home/user/storage/new_image.png', must be one of: VersionId, SSECustomerAlgorithm, SSECustomerKey, SSECustomerKeyMD5, RequestPayer
```

I must be doing something wrong but I'm following the example in the docs. Can someone help me specify a local directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking into the docs, you're providing an extra parameter

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket('mybucket').download_file('hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

From the docs, hello.txt is the name of the object on the bucket and /tmp/hello.txt is the path on your device, so the correct way would be

```
s3.Bucket(bucket).download_file(file, '/home/user/storage/new_image.png')
```